# RX 5500 XT Ubuntu 20.10 Instability, Crashing ([drm:amdgpu_dm_commit_planes.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Waiting for fences timed out!)

Tags: kernel, amd-graphics, crash, amdgpu

I've recently built an all-AMD system, with a Ryzen 7 3700X CPU and an RX 5500 XT Phantom D Gaming GPU. I have an Aorus Pro Wifi Motherboard and 32GB of Trident Z Neo RAM, with XMP enabled.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.10, with the 5.6.13-050613-generic kernel.

I've been having repeated issues with the amdgpu drivers freezing GNOME and all the windows on the screen, but not the mouse. A power cycle is needed to fix the issue, although SSH'ing into the machine works fine (so the kernel isn't hung).

Here is an excerpt of a kernel log from that crash:

```
635:May 17 16:29:09 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: [gfxhub] page fault (src_id:0 ring:40 vmid:0 pasid:0, for process  pid 0 thread  pid 0)
636:May 17 16:29:09 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0:   in page starting at address 0x0000000000888000 from client 27
637:May 17 16:29:09 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: GCVM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00041C50
638:May 17 16:29:09 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0:          MORE_FAULTS: 0x0
639:May 17 16:29:09 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0:          WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
640:May 17 16:29:09 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0:          PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x5
641:May 17 16:29:09 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0:          MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
642:May 17 16:29:09 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0:          RW: 0x1
645:May 17 16:29:19 arctic kernel: [drm:amdgpu_dm_commit_planes.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Waiting for fences timed out!
646:May 17 16:29:19 arctic kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring sdma1 timeout, signaled seq=10870, emitted seq=10872
647:May 17 16:29:19 arctic kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Process information: process  pid 0 thread  pid 0
648:May 17 16:29:19 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: GPU reset begin!
649:May 17 16:29:21 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: GPU reset succeeded, trying to resume
654:May 17 16:29:21 arctic kernel: amdgpu: [powerplay] SMU is resuming...
655:May 17 16:29:21 arctic kernel: amdgpu: [powerplay] SMU is resumed successfully!
659:May 17 16:29:22 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring gfx_0.0.0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 0
660:May 17 16:29:22 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring comp_1.0.0 uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 0
661:May 17 16:29:22 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring comp_1.1.0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 0
662:May 17 16:29:22 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring comp_1.2.0 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 0
663:May 17 16:29:22 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring comp_1.3.0 uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 0
664:May 17 16:29:22 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring comp_1.0.1 uses VM inv eng 7 on hub 0
665:May 17 16:29:22 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring comp_1.1.1 uses VM inv eng 8 on hub 0
666:May 17 16:29:22 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring comp_1.2.1 uses VM inv eng 9 on hub 0
667:May 17 16:29:22 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring comp_1.3.1 uses VM inv eng 10 on hub 0
668:May 17 16:29:22 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring kiq_2.1.0 uses VM inv eng 11 on hub 0
669:May 17 16:29:22 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring sdma0 uses VM inv eng 12 on hub 0
670:May 17 16:29:22 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring sdma1 uses VM inv eng 13 on hub 0
671:May 17 16:29:22 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring vcn_dec uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 1
672:May 17 16:29:22 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring vcn_enc0 uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 1
673:May 17 16:29:22 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring vcn_enc1 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 1
674:May 17 16:29:22 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring jpeg_dec uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 1
680:May 17 16:29:22 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: GPU reset(1) succeeded!
688:May 17 16:29:22 arctic /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2329]: amdgpu: amdgpu_cs_query_fence_status failed.
689:May 17 16:29:22 arctic gnome-shell[2678]: amdgpu: amdgpu_cs_query_fence_status failed.
709:May 17 16:33:23 arctic kernel: [drm:mod_hdcp_add_display_topology [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to add display topology, DTM TA is not initialized.
728:May 17 16:39:00 arctic kernel: [drm:mod_hdcp_add_display_topology [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to add display topology, DTM TA is not initialized.
852:May 17 16:49:44 arctic kernel: [drm:mod_hdcp_add_display_topology [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to add display topology, DTM TA is not initialized.
917:May 17 20:12:32 arctic kernel: [drm:mod_hdcp_add_display_topology [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to add display topology, DTM TA is not initialized.
```

Here is a similar crash on 5.6.13:

```
May 18 03:41:05 arctic kernel: [drm:mod_hdcp_add_display_topology [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to add display topology, DTM TA is not initialized.
May 18 03:41:05 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: [gfxhub] page fault (src_id:0 ring:40 vmid:0 pasid:0, for process  pid 0 thread  pid 0)
May 18 03:41:05 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0:   in page starting at address 0x00000000008fc000 from client 27
May 18 03:41:05 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: GCVM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00041A50
May 18 03:41:05 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0:          MORE_FAULTS: 0x0
May 18 03:41:05 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0:          WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
May 18 03:41:05 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0:          PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x5
May 18 03:41:05 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0:          MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
May 18 03:41:05 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0:          RW: 0x1
May 18 03:41:16 arctic kernel: [drm:amdgpu_dm_commit_planes.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Waiting for fences timed out!
May 18 03:41:16 arctic kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring sdma0 timeout, signaled seq=6205, emitted seq=6208
May 18 03:41:16 arctic kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Process information: process  pid 0 thread  pid 0
May 18 03:41:16 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: GPU reset begin!
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: GPU reset succeeded, trying to resume
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: [drm] PCIE GART of 512M enabled (table at 0x0000008000E10000).
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: [drm] VRAM is lost due to GPU reset!
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: [drm] PSP is resuming...
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: [drm] reserve 0xa00000 from 0x81fe400000 for PSP TMR
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: amdgpu: [powerplay] SMU is resuming...
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: amdgpu: [powerplay] SMU is resumed successfully!
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: [drm] kiq ring mec 2 pipe 1 q 0
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: [drm] VCN decode and encode initialized successfully(under DPG Mode).
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: [drm] JPEG decode initialized successfully.
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring gfx_0.0.0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 0
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring comp_1.0.0 uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 0
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring comp_1.1.0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 0
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring comp_1.2.0 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 0
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring comp_1.3.0 uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 0
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring comp_1.0.1 uses VM inv eng 7 on hub 0
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring comp_1.1.1 uses VM inv eng 8 on hub 0
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring comp_1.2.1 uses VM inv eng 9 on hub 0
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring comp_1.3.1 uses VM inv eng 10 on hub 0
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring kiq_2.1.0 uses VM inv eng 11 on hub 0
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring sdma0 uses VM inv eng 12 on hub 0
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring sdma1 uses VM inv eng 13 on hub 0
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring vcn_dec uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 1
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring vcn_enc0 uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 1
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring vcn_enc1 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 1
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: ring jpeg_dec uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 1
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: [drm] recover vram bo from shadow start
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: [drm] recover vram bo from shadow done
May 18 03:41:18 arctic kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
```

Here are some logs (from a mix of kernel versions, sorry I'm not sure exactly which ones came from which kernel:

https://pastebin.com/ADL0JvHB

https://pastebin.com/vSprRyRx

I've upgraded from kernel 5.4 to 5.5.19 to 5.6.13, and issues are still present.

Here is a crash log from a time the display just randomly disconnected (kernel 5.6.13):

```
May 18 02:30:57 arctic kernel: [drm:amdgpu_dm_commit_planes.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Waiting for fences timed out!
May 18 02:30:57 arctic kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring gfx_0.0.0 timeout, signaled seq=167698, emitted seq=167700
May 18 02:30:57 arctic kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Process information: process Xorg pid 2090 thread Xorg:cs0 pid 2091
May 18 02:30:57 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: GPU reset begin!
May 18 02:30:59 arctic kernel: amdgpu: [powerplay] failed send message: DisallowGfxOff (42) param: 0x00000000 response 0xffffffc2
May 18 02:31:02 arctic /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2090]: (II) event12 - Logitech MX Master 3000: SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost.
May 18 02:31:02 arctic kernel: amdgpu: [powerplay] Msg issuing pre-check failed and SMU may be not in the right state!
May 18 02:31:02 arctic /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2090]: (EE) client bug: timer event12 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-194ms), your system is too slow
May 18 02:31:02 arctic kernel: [drm:gfx_v10_0_hw_fini [amdgpu]] *ERROR* KGQ disable failed
May 18 02:31:02 arctic kernel: [drm:gfx_v10_0_hw_fini [amdgpu]] *ERROR* KCQ disable failed
May 18 02:31:04 arctic kernel: amdgpu: [powerplay] Msg issuing pre-check failed and SMU may be not in the right state!
May 18 02:31:04 arctic kernel: [drm:amdgpu_device_ip_suspend_phase2 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* suspend of IP block <smu> failed -62
May 18 02:31:07 arctic kernel: amdgpu: [powerplay] Msg issuing pre-check failed and SMU may be not in the right state! May 18 02:31:07 arctic kernel: [drm:amdgpu_device_gpu_recover.cold [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ASIC reset failed with error, -62 for drm dev, 0000:0b:00.0
May 18 02:31:07 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: GPU reset(1) failed
May 18 02:31:07 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: GPU reset end with ret = -62
May 18 02:31:12 arctic /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2090]: (EE) client bug: timer event12 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-5ms), your system is too slow May
18 02:31:17 arctic kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring gfx_0.0.0 timeout, signaled seq=167700, emitted seq=167700
May 18 02:31:17 arctic kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Process information: process Xorg pid 2090 thread Xorg:cs0 pid 2091
May 18 02:31:17 arctic kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: GPU reset begin!
```

I've set AMD_DEBUG=nodma,nongg, but it doesn't help. I can update the BIOS on my motherboard, although I'm only one version off of most recent version, and it only provides "Memory enhancements." And I can try the proprietary `amdgpu-pro` drivers instead of the open-source `amdgpu` drivers. But I can't think of anything else. I've tried 3 separate kernels already... Anyone have ideas?

```
$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL Version"
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 20.0.6
```

Comment: I'm facing a very similar problem here.

Comment: I was never able to fix this problem. I "fixed" it by purchasing an nVidia GPU...

Comment: Seems like https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=254283 and https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/892 Based on those threads it seems the issues is fixed in Linux 5.7, but I'm not sure about that. Right now I suffer from those freezes myself.

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *groovy gorilla* [20.10] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.10 is 22 October (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/groovy-gorilla-release-schedule/15531) when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 is supported now and same problem happens on Ubuntu 20.04 for this hardware. Can you open the question again?

Answer (score 2):

I spent a better part of a day trying to solve this. I won't even mention everything I tried.

I could run two monitors, but the system froze (crashed, got corrupted graphics mem, semi-crashed, kernel panicked - you name it) as soon as I plugged in a third monitor.

The key log lines in `/var/log/syslog` were:

```
amdgpu: failed to write reg 28b4 wait reg 28c6 
amdgpu: failed to write reg 1a6f4 wait reg 1a706 
amdgpu: failed send message: NumOfDisplays (64)   param: 0x00000003 response 0xffffffc2 
amdgpu: Msg issuing pre-check failed and SMU may be not in the right state! [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] 
*ERROR* ring sdma0 timeout, signaled seq=3474, emitted seq=3476 [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]]
*ERROR* Process information: process  pid 0 thread  pid 0 amdgpu 0000:0a:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset begin! ...
```

I finally decided to upgrade to the latest 5.7 kernel I could find, as some people seem to have better luck with later version kernels.

In my case, I downloaded the `.deb` packages and installed them:

```
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.7.19/amd64/linux-headers-5.7.19-050719-generic_5.7.19-050719.202008270830_amd64.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.7.19/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.7.19-050719-generic_5.7.19-050719.202008270830_amd64.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.7.19/amd64/linux-modules-5.7.19-050719-generic_5.7.19-050719.202008270830_amd64.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.7.19/amd64/linux-headers-5.7.19-050719_5.7.19-050719.202008270830_all.deb
dpkg -i linux-*.deb
```

Worked straight away. All four monitors are working.

Hopefully, it won't all go pop as soon as I post this!